# Best use of str_replace(...) for multiple replacements

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to figure out the best way to do a multiple replace on a String in PHP and so far str_replace() seems quite useful.

I am replacing certain words with flags, to simplify colloquialisms in a dataset.

For example, [POSITIVE_ADJ] signifies a positive adjective and to replace the word 'great', I'd do this:

```
str_replace("great","[POSITIVE_ADJ]","Thank you for helping me, you're great at PHP!");
```

But, say if I were to have a set of multiple positive adjectives, loaded into a data structure such as an array:

```
$positive_adj = array("good", "great", "wonderful", "excellent");
```

Is there a better way to replace any of the $positive_adj strings in the main string with the flag, as opposed to looping through it? With multiple flag arrays and bigger sets of adjectives etc. I imagine multiple loops as long as their respective arrays would become very inefficient

Any more efficient solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Jordan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its fairly well explained [in the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

But here is a worked example

```
$positive_adj = ["good", "great", "wonderful", "excellent"];

str_replace($positive_adj,
            "[POSITIVE_ADJ]",
            "Its really good of you to help me, you are a great and wonderful person!"
        );
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do that, now I feel stupid! I'll accept your answer in a couple of minutes when it lets me. How embarrassing! Thank you for pointing this out to me!

Comment: Jordan, it's not embarrasing to ask questions here. In addition, you can also use str_replace() with 2 arrays, first for find, second to replace, both arrays must have the same number of elements.

Comment: There is no stupid. None of us are perfect, and very few are experts on everything. I help you this time, maybe you will help me next time